# Save centroids into txt file

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, save

I'm using Google Earth Engine with the Python API. I have this piece of code:

```py
centroids = imNDVI4.reduceToVectors(
        geometry = test2,
        geometryType = 'centroid',
        scale = 30,
        crs = 'EPSG:4326',
        eightConnected = True
    )
```

I want to save the centroids within this variable, into a TXT file as a list of coordinates. 
How can I do this?

Comment: can you give an example on how it would look like (the content of the txt file)?

Comment: Something like that:

ID  Centroids coordinates
1   [x1, y2];
2   ...;
3   ...;

(Every semicolon is a return to a new line)
Although I already solved the issue by saving into CSV, but I also would like to know how to save, if possible, into a TXT file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the info using `getInfo` and save it to local file

```
# put centroids in a list
centroids_list = centroids.toList(centroids.size()).map(lambda f: ee.Feature(f).geometry().centroid()).getInfo()

# get only coordinates
data = [p['coordinates'] for p in centroids_list]

# file name
filename = 'test.txt'

# write file
with open(filename, 'w+') as thefile:
    text = ""
    for i, p in enumerate(data):
        text += 'ID Centroids coordinates {} {}\n'.format(i, p)
    thefile.write(text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rodrigo, I will try and let you know!

Comment: It works very well, as I expected. Thank you again Rodrigo!